# Problem with my profile name

Tags: support, profile-page, real-name

I have an account at Stack Exchange which I have used to log in into the Stack Exchange app.
My problem is that it does not show my name. Instead it shows "**user153722**" as my name.
How to change my name to "**Aman Palariya**".

Comment: I searched for it but I couldn't find it. Thanks @sha

Comment: @Pat no problem, had trouble finding this one, found some totally out-dated questions before that, and too lazy to fix them, lol

Comment: I proposed it to become a faq question. Weird it isn't yet...